# Is there any restriction on maximum number of threads created using ExecutorService

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am creating an application which requires multiple processes to run in parallel. The number of processes to run is dynamic, it depends on the input received.

E.g., if the user wants information about three different things [car, bike, auto] then I need three separate thread to run each in parallel.

```
numberOfThreadsNeeded = getNumberOfThingsFromInput();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreadsNeeded);
```

Code Snippet:

public class ConsoleController {

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ConsoleController.class);

@Autowired
ConsoleCache consoleCache;

Metrics metrics;

public List<Feature> getConsoleData(List<String> featureIds, Map<String, Object> input, Metrics metrics) {
    this.metrics = metrics;
    List<FeatureModel> featureModels =
            featureIds
                    .stream()
                    .map(consoleCache::getFeature)
                    .collect(toList());

    Integer numberOfThreadsNeeded = getThreadCount(featureModels);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreadsNeeded);

    featureModels.stream()
            .map(f -> (Callable<Result>) () -> f.fetchData(input, metrics))
                    .map(executor::submit)
                    .collect(toList()));
```

The number of threads to be created varies from 1 to 100. Is it safe to define the `thread pool` size during initialization?
And also I want to know whether it is safe to run 100 `threads` in `parallel`?

Comment: Are you creating a brand-new executor per user request?

Comment: Yes. For each request, a separate executor instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard limit as per Java, but there might be a limit, for example, in the JVM implementation or the Operating System. So, practically speaking there is a limit. And there is a point where adding more threads can make the performance worse, not better. Also, there is a possibility of running out of memory.

The way you use ExecutorService is not the way it was intended to be used. Normally you would create a single ExecutorService with the threads limit number that is best suited for your environment.

Keep in mind that even if you really want all your tasks to be executed in parallel you won't be able to achieve it anyways given the hardware/software concurrency limitations.

BTW, if you still want to create an ExecutorService per request - don't forget to call its shutdown() method, otherwise the JVM won't be able to exit gracefully as there will be threads still hanging around.